# Android Pinterest animation- 3 separate bubbles spring out when longpress

Tags: android, spring, animation, pinterest

I am building an android app in which i want to create the animation similar to pinterest animation in which three bubbles came out in spring animation on long press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this library [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) by Facebook. It is a spring animation framework created by Facebook for its **Chat Heads**. I believe Pinterest uses Rebound for the animation and you should dig into Rebound for it.

Comment: Ya, i know that but this is not something i am looking for.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Isn't Pinterest menu created using Rebound?

Comment: Using spring animation is quite a job in Android. However if you wish to compromise quality for simplicity, there is a similar library for android. See here https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

Comment: Ok, i will look into it